# Molecular explanation for pressure

Tags: fluid-dynamics, momentum, transport-phenomena

According to [this post](https://www.quora.com/How-is-viscosity-the-diffusion-of-momentum), viscous stress is the result of molecular diffusion. More specifically, it's a transfer of momentum in a direction perpendicular to the direction of a velocity gradient. This got me wondering: is pressure also due to molecular diffusion? Is pressure just the transfer of momentum in the direction of the velocity gradient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Statistical physics**
In statistical physics one considers mainly the pressure of gas (liquid, solid) against the walls of the container. This indeed arises from the molecular collisions, in which the molecules are scattered from the walls of the container, transferring to the walls their momentum. Any basic statistical physics text provides the calculation (usually as the derivation of the ideal gas law).

**Fluid dynamics**
In fluid dynamics the situation is a bit trickier, since there is no apparent surface against which the molecules collide. In fact, fluid dynamics is valid only on the scales big compared to the diffusion length, i.e., indeed, we can speak of pressure only when we discuss layers of liquid that are sufficiently thick, so that all the molecules coming from one layer collide and lose their momentum, transferring it to the next layer of the liquid, and thus creating pressure.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful reply. So on a large enough length scale, BOTH viscous stress and pressure can be thought of as being due to collisions between molecules from a region of high momentum and molecules from a region of low momentum? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, they are different components of the total stress tensor ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscous_stress_tensor#The_viscous_stress_tensor)).